# XCode not saving files

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm not able to save any file with xcode , 'm getting the following warning when i save/run the code "The document XXXXXX could not be saved. You don’t have permission. To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.". I have tried all the solutions provided in other questions for this issue, but that does not help. Does anyone have a solution for this ?. Everything was fine till last week and this week, I installed JIRA and mysql after which I started facing this issue. Not sure if JIRA & mysql installations has caused this issue, tried uninstalling these, no hopes yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with permissions on your mac, to solve this issue, try reset permissions of your user by using this [tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/), if it didn't success, use this [solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3897436?start=0&tstart=0) to resolve the problem.